# This is a piece of code from 'largest rectangular area in a Histogram. How is this piece of code working?

Tags: python, stack

```
#given
#histogram[top_of_stack] = 6
#index = 1
#stack is empty


area = (histogram[top_of_stack] * 
               ((index - stack[-1] - 1)  
               if stack else index))
```

I was going through the solution code of 'Largest Rectangular Area in a Histogram'. There I    couldn't understand the following code. why are we writing `((index - stack[-1] - 1) if stack else index)` and how is this working? And what if `index = 1` and `stack is empty`. Source code is https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/largest-rectangle-under-histogram/?ref=lbpThanks for any help!

Comment: What language is that code written in? Please always add the relevant language tag when posting questions including code. Also please take some time to read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take the SO [tour], read [ask], as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). Lastly please learn how to [edit] your questions to improve them (like adding language tag, or telling us the problem you try to solve).

Comment: This code is written in python. and this code is from geeksforgeeks.